# Xcode: Return a Float from an NSMutableArray in heightForCellAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

**Scenario** = I have a PFQueryTableViewController that needs different sized cells at each indexPath depending upon values returned from the query. If the image is "Landscape size" that would be one size, and if its "Portrait size" than that is another.

1) I create a NSMutableArray in .h file to hold the sizes.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *rowHeightArray;
```

2) For each objects I check for the value in cellForRowAtIndexPath and add it to the array.

```
if ([object[@"orientation"] isEqual:@"left"] || [object[@"orientation"] isEqual:@"right"]) {

    [rowHeightArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:378]];
}

else {

    [rowHeightArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:488]];
}
```

(there are more than just these two possibilities but I think that is enough to get the point across)

**ISSUES**

3) Now I need to place the correct height to the correct cell. Problem is when I try...

```
return self.rowHeightArray[indexPath.row];
```

In heightForRowAtIndexPath it "yells" at me with:

```
returning 'id' from a function with an incompatible result type 'CGFloat' (aka 'float')
```

and alternatively I also tried

```
return [self.rowHeightArray[indexPath.row]floatValue]
```

this stops "yelling" at me but when i try to run this it errors out:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

**Question** = How do I accomplish what I'm trying to do here and have it 'work'?

Comment: Read the last error. It tells you the problem. `rowHeightArray` is empty.

Comment: I suppose I should thank you for not writing that as an answer lol. If you don't mind, why is it empty? Is it because cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called _after_ heightForRowAtIndexPath? If so, how do I populate the NSMutableArray with the appropriate data **before** heightForRowAtIndexPath gets called?

Comment: @BillyA - PFTableVC gives you a hook: - (void)objectsDidLoad:...  Run through them there to build the float array.  (I think) that's called before the vc reloads its table.

Comment: Thanks danh. I'm going to try that right now.

Comment: Hey danh, Im working on this and I'm kind of cornfused. How do I build the float array inside the objectsDidLoad method to extract the correct information? Before in my question I did the `if ([object[@"orientation"] isEqual:@"left"] || [object[@"orientation"] isEqual:@"right"])` and then did what I needed to do. How do I get the objectAtIndex: inside of the objectsDidLoad when they don't give you a `object` to be able to objectAtIndex: with?

Comment: I apologize if I did not explain my question the best way. I mean, in heightForRowAtIndexPath they give you a parameter called `indexPath`. That is what allows me to go `PFObject* object = [self.objects objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];` so I can access what I'm looking for. But if you notice, objectsDidLoad does not have an `indexPath` parameter that goes with it. How do I access the information then?

Comment: See my answer, elaborating on @AaronBrager 's correct answer.  Assuming it works, you should mark his correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on @AaronBrager's correct answer, load, then build the float array before the datasource gets called.  This can be done in the hook the PFTable vc gives you called.  To answer your question in comments, there's no need for the indexPath, since we know that the self.objects array indexes, the indexes you build here, and the indexes passed to the datasource method will all correspond (0..self.objects.count-1):

```
- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {

    self.rowHeightArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (PFObject *object in self.objects) {
        NSString *orientation = object[@"orientation"];
        NSNumber *height;
        if ([orientation isEqualToString:@"left"] || [orientation isEqualToString:@"right"]) {
            height = @378.0;
        } else {
            height = @488.0;
        }
        [self.rowHeightArray addObject: height];
    }
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Two problems:

1. `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called *before* `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. So your current approach is calculating the height too late. You need to calculate it in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` or earlier (in `viewDidLoad`, or when your `PFQuery` finishes, for example).
2. You're returning an `NSNumber` object not a `CGFloat`. You need to unbox it:

   ```
   NSNumber *heightNumber = self.rowHeightArray[indexPath.row];
   return [heightNumber floatValue];
   ```

Of course this won't work with your current implementation, since (as rmaddy points out) `self.rowHeightArray` is empty. So if you want to use this array, you need to make sure it's populated before `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` gets called.

Comment: Populate it when the query finishes.  Then reload the table.

Comment: Hey Aaron thanks for the reply! Im working on this now, but just a question. Correct me if I'm wrong (because I probably am), I thought making a `NSNumber` with the `numberWithFloat` made it a CGFloat.

Comment: That's wrong. NSNumber is an object wrapper around a non-object number. (`NSNumber` is an object but `CGFloat` isn't.)